# Issue enumerating monitors in Windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi

My task is to count the number of current monitors (screens) attached to the computer where my user-mode code below is running:

```
int nCnt = 0;
if(!EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, countMonitorsProc, (LPARAM)&nCnt))
{
    //Error
}

BOOL countMonitorsProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    int* pCnt = (int*)dwData;
    (*pCnt)++;

    return TRUE;
}
```

It works in most cases, but on some systems the `EnumDisplayMonitors` returns FALSE. Example of such system: my laptop where I attached an external monitor and shut the lid on it.

I'm curious, do I use the right approach for counting attached monitors?

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return?

Comment: Please don't seed unnecessary tags into the title - that's what the tags section is for. Thanks :)

Comment: @alk: According to MSDN, `GetLastError` is not used for that API.

Comment: So what does it return though? Try it.

Comment: I hate windows - *sigh*

Comment: Is the callback ever called?

Comment: If all you want to do is get the count of installed monitors, you're doing it wrong. `nCnt = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS);` would be the proper way.

Comment: What does GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS) display in the same situation?

Comment: It's a good idea. What I need this for is to know if there're any external monitors plugged in to the laptop. For instance, I need to know if, for instance, I have any external monitors plugged in with the laptop lid closed. (I know how to get a notification of lid-closed.)

Answer (score 0):

If all you're wanting to know is how many monitors are connected, there should be no need to call `EnumDisplayMonitors`. The proper way to do this for physical (non-virtual) monitors is via [GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), with the index `SM_CMONITORS`.

```
SM_CMONITORS         The number of display monitors on a desktop. For more
80                   information, see the Remarks section in this topic.
```

From the Remarks section

> GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS) counts only visible display monitors. This is different from EnumDisplayMonitors, which enumerates both visible display monitors and invisible pseudo-monitors that are associated with mirroring drivers. An invisible pseudo-monitor is associated with a pseudo-device used to mirror application drawing for remoting or other purposes.

The call then simply becomes

```
nCnt = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS);
```